# How to listen windows account change password event

Tags: c#, windows

Now I need create a windows service that listen to user account password changed event. 
The windows service will start when the computer turned on, and if current account changed his password,or other account's password, then I need to log it to an txt file.
Can I listen to the change password event in C# programming?

Anyone can help me ? A lot of thanks..

Comment: why don't you read it out of the system logs periodically?

Comment: Are u talking about changing the windows account's password ?

Comment: Do you mean you just want to know when a password got changed or do you want to actually know the password?

Comment: @ChrisWue Want to know a password got changed ,no what the password be Thanks.

Comment: @Sangram yes, windows account's password change event.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be easy for you to track it, but I suggest to have a background process worker using [Windows Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and try to read this link about [How Password Modification Dates Are Stored](http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory%E2%80%94How_Password_Modification_Dates_Are_Stored).

This will give you the headstart for the goal you want to achieve.  Remember that you can use his identity in his computer to check in an interval manner as windows services do.  This will track the last password change date of his username. The key here is checking the date values from previous one and the current value from your Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by comments you can use the windows [Event Logs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815314). In the linked KB article is a sample of how to listen to event notifications. You only need to figure out the exact event you need to listen to.